# Joomla Popup that closes on a click anywhere

Tags: joomla, popup

I wanted to make a popup that loads on the index page instantly and then can close if you click anywhere. I put together a code that works.  However, when I put it into a custom module, I do not like how it displays. So I put it in the html file for the index page. It works great, however, it loads on every page as the other articles load off the index page as well.

Is there any extension or anyway I can make my code only display when the main index page is loaded and no other time?
I appreciate the help.

````
#popupContainer {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
}

#popup {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 100px;
    background-color:#000000;
    background-image: url(http://www.pureohiowellness.com/rd/images/logo25.png);
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:6px outset #111;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:20px;
    line-height:2.6;
                          }
                          
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {   
    #popup{
        width:75%;
    } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {      
    #popup{      
        width:75%;
    } 
} 
@media (min-width: 992px) {      
      #popup{        
          width:75%;
      } 
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {    
     #popup{         
        width:75%;
     } 
}

    
#popupExit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #833;
}

#popupExit p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#popupContainer #popup p {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-size: 36px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>


<div id="popupContainer">
  <div id="popup">
            <div id="popupExit">
              
            </div>
            <p>LONDON LOCATION NOW OPEN!  ONLY 20 MINUTES FROM DOWNTOWN COLUMBUS!!</p>
        </div>
</div>
   
<script type="application/javascript">

function hidePopup(event) {
    document.getElementById("popupContainer").style.display = 'none';
    blockClick(event)    
}

function blockClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

document.getElementById("popupContainer").onclick = hidePopup;
document.getElementById("popupExit").onclick = hidePopup;
document.getElementById("popup").onclick = blockClick;
</script>```
````

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please create a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account.  Please ask all Joomla questions at JSE.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to implement that:

1. have a dedicated template style for your homepage and add your code only there. This is actually a pretty nice way but duplicates your template code.
2. create a custom module, let it be only visible on the homepage. The module needs to add the CSS/JS and some more JS code which adds appends your popupContainer to the document body instead of rendering it right away. You could create a custom module or a simple HTML-capable module. That way is pretty hacky, but will do that you want to achieve. Make sure you append your Event Listeners after you added the popup to the DOM.